# std::atomic with no conversion operators

Tags: c++, atomic, stdatomic

I need to refactor some C++ code that needs some accesses to become atomic.

`std::atomic` is nice, but can be assigned from and converted to `value_type`, which means that existing call sites are taken over without complaint.

Is there a variant of std::atomic that requires me to explicitly call `load()`/`store()`/`compare_exchange_weak` everywhere?

Comment: I am not aware of such variant. But you can write it yourself as a wrapper for `std::atomic`, exposing only the methods you want.

Comment: Why do you want to explicitly call load()/store()/compare_exchange_weak everywhere?

Comment: I would just manually re-name the field from, say `m_value` to `m_atomicValue`. Then you have to go around and change the name everywhere manually anyway, so you can examine where it is passed to external functions.

Comment: @Caleth: Seems reasonable to me as a coding-style choice, to highlight the shared-variable accesses and make it easier to spot them in code that also uses some local vars.  If you want to enforce that, not providing operator= and cast overloads seems a good way.  Also, if you intend to only use `acquire` / `release` operations, the default `seq_cst` is slower so you want to catch anywhere you forgot and used it implicitly.  (For that you'd also want to delete the operator++ and operator-- overloads.  Making the memory-order arg not defaulted would be useful but maybe not worth the effort.)

Comment: fwiw, `std::atomic< wrapper<T>>` would let you choose between explicit from/to `T` and implicit from/to `wrapper<T>`